# Require once/include not finding correct file laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, oauth

[image]Require once/include in my laravel project is not functioning properly. I am using the correct path however i continue to get the same error. I can see the file is in the designated space. What could cause this? Here is my code:

```
    @extends('apps.admin')
    @section('main')
<?php
            include(app_path().'vendor/j7mbo/twitter-api-php/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
            $settings = array(
                'oauth_access_token' => "token",
                'oauth_access_token_secret' => "token",
                'consumer_key' => "token",
                'consumer_secret' => "token"
            );

            $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
            $getfield = '?q=#nerd';
            $requestMethod = 'GET';

            $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
            $response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                ->performRequest();

            var_dump(json_decode($response));
            ?>
@stop
```

I also tried this:

```
require_once('vendor/j7mbo/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
```

and this:

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
```

errors:

```
include(/var/www/web/elephantegin/htdocs/app/vendor/j7mbo/twitter-api-php/TwitterAPIExchange.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: /var/www/web/elephantegin/htdocs/resources/views/socialApps/twitter.blade.php)
```

errror:

```
main(): Failed opening required '/vendor/j7mbo/TwitterAPIExchange.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/var/www/web/elephantegin/htdocs')
```

Comment: Where does your code lives? Have you checked folder/file permissions? And what does the error say?

Comment: Just a side note, why are you including files and perform such logic in a view

Comment: i added the errors. Is this the wrong way to do this? This is the first time trying to make calls to twitter api. I was following the tutorial on the github project

Comment: what is the correct way to do this im really curious

Comment: Why won't you get the response in the Controller and pass it to the view. Views just display data retrieved from Controllers.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks.. Do you know anything else about using this call within laravel? Now its telling me that i can't redifine the class?? Im struggling through this process and have been reading twitter api all week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the file incorrectly, use the correct path:

```
        include(app_path().'../vendor/j7mbo/twitter-api-php/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
```